# Why doesn't edge return a DirectedEdge?

Tags: groovy

I have ran into an issue when using traits. The following code overrides newEdge using a trait.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
class Edge {}
trait DirectedEdge {}
class Graph {
    def edge() {
        newEdge()
    }
    def newEdge() {
        return new Edge()
    }
}
trait DirectedGraph {
    def newEdge() {
        return new Edge().withTraits(DirectedEdge)
    }
}

def graph = new Graph()
assert graph.newEdge() instanceof Edge : 'newEdge returns Edge'
assert graph.edge() instanceof Edge : 'edge returns an Edge'

def dgraph = new Graph() as DirectedGraph
assert dgraph.newEdge() instanceof DirectedEdge : 'newEdge returns DirectedEdge'
assert dgraph.edge() instanceof DirectedEdge : 'edge returns DirectedEdge'
```

The first two asserts show the behavior without the DirectedGraph trait. The next trait shows the expected behavior with DirectedGraph but the trait's method does not appear to be used in the last assert.

The last assert fails with.

```
Caught: java.lang.AssertionError: edge returns DirectedEdge. Expression: (dgraph.edge() instanceof DirectedEdge)
java.lang.AssertionError: edge returns DirectedEdge. Expression: (dgraph.edge() instanceof DirectedEdge)
```

I was wondering how I could fix this behavior so the last assert can pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happens in `def dgraph = new Graph() as DirectedGraph` semantically:

```
class MyProxy implements DirectedGraph {
    Graph myGraph

    MyProxy(Graph graph) {
        myGraph = graph
    }

    def invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
        myGraph.invokeMethod(name, args)
    }
}

def dgraph = new MyProxy(new Graph())
```

Such object implements a trait and delegates all undefined calls to original object, i.e. `Graph` instance.

`assert dgraph.newEdge() instanceof DirectedEdge` works because `newEdge` method is derived from the trait.
`assert dgraph.edge() instanceof DirectedEdge` fails because there is no `edge` method, this call is delegated to original `Graph` instance, which in turn has no knowledge about proxy wrapper.

This can be implemented with pure class inheritance:

```
class Edge {}

class DirectedEdge extends Edge {}

class Graph {
    def edge() { newEdge() }
    def newEdge() { new Edge() }
}

class DirectedGraph extends Graph {
    def newEdge() { new DirectedEdge() }
}

def graph = new Graph()
assert graph.newEdge() instanceof Edge
assert graph.edge() instanceof Edge

def dgraph = new DirectedGraph()
assert dgraph.newEdge() instanceof DirectedEdge
assert dgraph.edge() instanceof DirectedEdge
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This actually fills in a lot of gaps in my knowledge. I am probably going to go with something like this

    graph.metaClass.newEdge = { ->
            return graph.&newEdge().withTraits(DirectedEdge)
    }

This is to help avoid complexity when Weight and Attributes are added.

Comment: @JohnMercier You are welcome! I advise not to go with metaclass magic, please, consider inheritance. You may provide more details of what you want to achieve, so I could help you with another solution.

Comment: I'm not sure inheritance will work. This is the project https://github.com/moaxcp/graph-dsl. My goal is to make a script with a graph as the delegate. I would like to make it easy to change a graph to a directed graph using an apply method.